# Как правильно прочитать время из файла

Tags: c++, время, unixtimestamp

Возникла задачка с преведением времени.

Дано: тесктовый файл в которм лежат 2е даты, лежет друг за другом в таком виде`14812649901512714590`. Есть структура в кторою нужно их прочитать

```
struct TimePeriod
{
time_t beg;
time_t end;

}
```

Файл читаю так

```
TimePeriod* Tik = new TimePeriod;
     ifstream in(path,ifstream::binary);
     if(!in)
     {
          cout << "Ошибка открытия файла " << path << endl;
     }
     else
     {
          cout << "Файл прочитан" << path << endl;
     }
     in.read((char*)Tik, sizeof (TimePeriod))
```

при этом в полях `Tik` лежат не те даты которые записанны в файл.
Подозрение на проблему с приобразованием типов. Подскажите как реализовать так чтобы при чтение в структуре лежали верные значения из файла? 
P.S. ОС Ubuntu 14.04 IDE QtCreator 3.5.1 QT 5.5.1 g++ 4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они лежат, как я понимаю, в текстовом виде - кстати, без разделителя... - а читаете вы их как бинарные.

Задача неоднозначна... но, пожалуй, в предположении, что даты не так уж далеко отстоят одна от другой, я бы просто считывал строку, делил на две, и считывал эти значения в структуру.

Что-то вроде

```
struct TimePeriod
{
    time_t beg;
    time_t end;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    ifstream in("data");
    if(!in)
    {
        cout << "ЋиЁЎЄ  ®вЄалвЁп д ©«  " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "” ©« ®вЄалв" << endl;
    }
    string s;
    in >> s;
    TimePeriod t;
    int pos = s.length()/2;
    t.beg = stol(s.substr(0,pos));
    t.end = stol(s.substr(pos));

    cout << t.beg << "  " << t.end << endl;

}
```

Comment: я правильно понял что нужно прочитать все строку как символы? а потом эти символы конвертировать во время?

Comment: Ну, вот примерно так, как я дописал в ответе. Там точно пробела между временами нет?

Comment: Точно нет. сам это время туда писал)

Comment: Ну во теперь и расхлебываете... Писали как текст, читаете бинарно...

Answer (score 1):

Для удобства повторного использования определили бы вы для своей структуры пару операторов:

(на основе кода [пользователя Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry))

```
istream& operator>> (istream& src, TimePeriod& dst)
{
  string tmp;
  src >> tmp;
  auto pos = tmp.length()/2;
  dst.beg = stol(tmp.substr(0,pos));
  dst.end = stol(tmp.substr(pos));
  return src;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& dst, const TimePeriod& src)
{
  dst << src.beg << src.end;
  return dst;
}
```

И пользовались бы ими в дальнейшем:

```
TimePeriod tp;

ifstream in("data");
in >> tp;
cout << tp << endl;
```

И изменить бы вам формат сохранения, а то  в некоторых случаях неоднозначно получается:

```
TimePeriod tp;
tp.beg = 14812;
tp.end = 1512714590;
```

После записи-чтения превратится в:

```
tp.beg = 1481215;
tp.end = 12714590;
```